# Help solving this differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, assumptions, numerical-value

I am trying to solve this differential equation
$$ y^{''}(x) + \frac{6}{x} y^{'}(x) +14 y(x) = -4 y(x) \; \ln(y(x)),\; x > 0$$
subject to the boundary conditions $y(0) =  1,\;y^{'}(0) = 0$. The exact solution is $y(x) = e^{-x^2}$. But I got some errors and I need some help to find a workaround.
This is what I tried:

```
ClearAll[y, x, eq, ics]
 
eq = y''[x] + 6/x * y'[x] + 14*y[x] == -4*y[x]*Log[y[x]]
ics = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}
NDSolve[{eq, ics}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I got this error messages:

**Power::infinite expression 1/0 encountered.**

So I tried this:

```
Assuming[x > 0, NDSolve[{eq, ics}, y, {x,0,1}]]
```

But got the same error... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your equation there is a term `1/x`. Clearly, this is not defined at x==0. Therefore, look at your problem and decide if you really need to start at zero. If so start at a small number.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your comment, at $x == 0$ the boundary conditions must hold and the differential equation is considered for $ x >0$.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why `DSolve` can't solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround:

```
sol = With[{e = 10^-30},NDSolve[{y''[x] + 6/x*y'[x] + 14*y[x] == -4*y[x]*Log[y[x]], 
y[e] == 1, y'[e] == 0}, y, {x, e, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 29]];

Plot[{y[x] /. sol, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, 10^-30, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}]

Plot[(y[x] /. sol) - Exp[-x^2], {x, 10^-30, 1}](*Errors*)
```

Answer (score 3):

For small $x$ the ODE can be reformulated

```
eq = 6 y'[x] + 14 x*y[x] == -4 x*y[x]*Log[y[x]];
ics = {y[0] == 1};
z = NDSolveValue[{eq, ics}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
```

*Correction:* coefficient in front of $y'(x)$ should be 7 not 6.

This solution can be used to obtain a solution on the remaining interval starting from a small number `a`

```
a = 0.1;
eq = y''[x] + 6/x*y'[x] + 14*y[x] == -4*y[x]*Log[y[x]];
ics = {y[a] == z[a], y'[a] == z'[a]};
w = NDSolveValue[{eq, ics}, y, {x, a, 1}];
```

Finally define a composite function and plot the difference to the analytic solution

```
ys[x_] := Piecewise[{{z[x], x <= a}, {w[x], x > a}}]
Plot[{ys[x] - Exp[-x^2]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I selected on purpose a rather large value of $a$ to demonstrate the principle. Already by setting $a=10^{-2}$, the error is reduced below $10^{-8}$ (`WorkingPrecision` needs to be increased in order to achieve that).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I guess that for small $x$ the coefficient of $y^{'}$ in the reformulated equation should be $7$ ?

Comment: @Clifford Good point. It is hard to see at the first sight.